# Making a GET request in BackBone using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am new to backbone js and have been working on this project for the last couple of days - I am trying to make an ajax get request inside the backbone view, but stuck on how to implement it.  What am I doing wrong inside the success function?

View:

```
 var PictureView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#app",        
        template: _.template('<img src = <%=image%>/>')        
        events: {
            //'
            "click .button": this.render(); //?
        },               
        render: function() {
            var that = this; // to fix that `this` refers to in the callback
            $.ajax({
                    var apiKey = "willreplacetomykey";
                    url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?",
                    method: 'flickr.photos.search',
                    api_key: apiKey,
                    format: 'json',
                    nojsoncallback: 1,
                    per_page: 1
                    success: function(result) {
                        //do the setting and rendering.
                        this.model.set({
                            image: result
                        })
                        return this.$el.html(this.template((this.model.attributes));
                        }        
                    });
            });       

    }        
    })

Model:

    var Picture = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {        
            image: ""
        },        
        initialize: function() {       

        },        
        addImage: function() {
            //?
        },        
    });
```

Comment: `this.model` is scoped to the success function, perhaps changing it to `that.model` to correct your scoping issue might fix it?

Comment: There are a lot of things backbone can help you with here, but I think the main problem is that you are not utilizing it's tools for seperating concerns. You should try to seperate the data layer from the presentation layer. Currently, if you wanted to use a different view for your model, you would have to write the ajax call again. Consider the documentation: Models are the heart of any JavaScript application, containing the interactive data as well as a large part of the logic surrounding it: conversions, validations, computed properties, and access control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your success function has lost the `this` context that you are looking for, and you aren't able to return anything out of the success callback. The easiest way to fix the `this` binding would be to do a function bind:

```
success: function(result) {
  this.model.set({
    image: result
  })

  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));        
}.bind(this)
```

Or you could use the `that` variable you created as such:

```
success: function(result) {
  that.model.set({
    image: result
  })

  that.$el.html(that.template(that.model.toJSON()));        
}
```

Or you could even have the success callback fire off another function on the view/model and pass the results to it if you need to do some more complicated stuff:

```
success: function(result) {
  this.model.setResults(results);
}
```

And on the model:

```
setResults: function(results) {
  // do things with results
}
```